# Parent class's method called by using which child class in php?

Tags: php, oop

Suppose I have the following scenario.

```
class Base {
    public static function functionA() {
        // I want to know this method is called by which child class's instance
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    public static function someFunc() {}
}

class AnotherChild extends Base {
    public static function someOtherFunc() {}
}

// Now I call the static function from the Base class
Child::functionA();
AnotherChild::functionA();
```

By using the above example, how could I detect the method `functionA()` is called by using `Child` or `AnotherChild` class. Is it possible?

Comment: Where do you want to detect this and more importantly, why?

Comment: I want to detect this inside the `Base` class's  `functionA()` method. I need this I want to do something different at the method based on the child class.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to get class names but the only way I now of to get the actual class that was called:

```
class Base {
    public static function functionA() {
        echo get_called_class();
    }
}
```